# External HDD not mounting

Tags: usb, mount, filesystem, external-hdd

So, basically, from one day to another, my external HDD is not being auto mount in Ubuntu 16.04

I did not make any change in the OS
The only change I've made it's that I bought a new cable for the external HDD cause the previous one was loosy.

This is the output of fdisk -l

I reckon that the sdb1 it's for the external disk

> Disk /dev/sda: 149,1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disklabel type: dos
>   Disk identifier: 0x8194093d
>
> Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
>   /dev/sda1  *         2048 304390143 304388096 145,1G 83 Linux
>   /dev/sda2       304392190 312580095   8187906   3,9G  5 Extended
>   /dev/sda5       304392192 312580095   8187904   3,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000170586112 bytes, 1953458176 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disklabel type: dos
>   Disk identifier: 0x00023f15
>   Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
>   /dev/sdb1  *     2048 1953458175 1953456128 931,5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

any help please?

I've already try in all 3 usb ports
The External HDD light blinks makes "a work like" sound
Reboot laptop, but nothing

**EDIT1**

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 145,1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   3,9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 931,5G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

sudo mount -t exFAT /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'exFAT'

sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x44414142  size: 1024   
usa_ofs:       8572  usa_count: 29550: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x44414142)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.

**unplugged disk**
ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda5


**plugged disk**

ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda5
sdb
sdb1
```

I've also connected to a Windows computer. It detects correctly the USB Driver, but on "My Computer" the disk appears with no info at all.
I've run
chkdisk /f x: (where x is the disk unit)
and the test said it fail basically. And reboot Windows twice. No change at all.

Comment: Exactly what errors did chkdsk show? It sounds like a corrupt file system, or a hardware problem.

Comment: @heynnema Windows cannot repair master file table. I've tried chkdsk /f and /r but the same result.

Comment: If you start the `Disks` application in Ubuntu, and go to the "hamburger" icon, and select "SMART Data & Tests", review the data, and run the tests.

Comment: That option is unavailable for that disk, is greyed out.

Comment: Did you select the disk in the left pane before trying to select SMART? When you say you replaced the USB cable because it was "loosy", what do you mean? What is light blinks makes "a work like" sound... can you describe the sound better? Did this external disk used to work in Ubuntu? Do you have backups of the data?

Comment: When I go to "Disk" app, If I select the external HDD (the one with the issue) i do not have the option. If I select the internal Disk I have it. With loosy I mean that the cable was not working well, I had to put the cable in a specific way in order that the notebook detect the disk. The disk has a led light, when it's working (data being reading or writing) it blinks, if it0s connected with no work, it stays on. With the sound I mean like any regular disk sound when it's working. The external disk work in Ubuntu for the last 5 years or so.

Comment: This is the part that hurt the most for me, I do not have a backup of this data, i was about to buy another external HDD to do this...

Comment: It sure sounds like you've got a hardware problem with either the case or the drive. Any chance that you could remove the drive from the case and install it on another computer (like a desktop) and see if it works there?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood the last part. Do you want to install the external HDD as an internal HD on another computer? It's and external HDD and I've tried to connect to two different computers with the same results, it does not mount.

Comment: Yes, exactly. As an internal drive on another (desktop) computer. I want to eliminate the case as a failure point. If the drive fails on another computer, it's reformat time, or replacement time.

Comment: It'll be a good try I guess, but I do not have a desktop computer to do that. for all the symptoms (specially the one when I plugged into Windows, that says that I have to format the disk) I do not think that the disk is broken physically, it is just corrupt,. My main concern right now it's to get back all the data that is in there.

Comment: If it's corrupt, plan on getting zero back. Same if it's a bad HDD. A backup would have been helpful. Take the bare drive to a local computer shop and ask them to hook it up to one of their test jigs and non-destructively test the drive.

Comment: Ehm, I not lost any hope yet so I'll wait to see if I can solve this (also, now it's kinda personal). For now, I am with Photorec trying to see what can I recover. If I can recover most of the things that I want, I'll format the disk. Thanks a lot for your help though