# Want to boot Ubuntu from detachable external HDD, but external HDD not mounted at the boot and hence not enlisted

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have gotten  [Haier Y11b tablet PC](http://www.haier.com/pk/products/pc/Tablet_PC/y11b.shtml) containing two built in HDDs, one is 30 GB SSD with Windows 10 pre-installed and second one is detachable 500 GB (connected through USB port). I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on 500 GB using boo-table Flash drive with 4 GB swap area and 124 GB root. After successful installation when machine rebooted and I selected Ubuntu OS from boot menu it opens the grub2 terminal in which Linux is not enlisted.
I have tried everything i.e., secure boot off etc. I think the issue is that machine doesn't mount the external HDD at the boot because I couldn't find it.

From previous many days, I have checked many thing e.g., [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938816/external-hdd-not-mounting) ,[link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/569972/usb-drive-not-detected-in-intel-efi-shell) etc. but it didn't work.

Following is the output of `lsblk` command from LiveBoot Ubuntu using USB Flash drive

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1  14.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14.5G  0 part /cdrom
loop0    7:0    0   1.4G  1 loop /rofs
sdc      8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdc2   8:34   0 237.8G  0 part /media/ubuntu/New Volume
├─sdc5   8:37   0 124.1G  0 part /media/ubuntu/5f730386-478e-4f81-a926-9b1f5b0cc
├─sdc3   8:35   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   100G  0 part /media/ubuntu/Installation
└─sdc4   8:36   0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sda      8:0    0  29.8G  0 disk 
├─sda4   8:4    0  1000M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  28.7G  0 part 
└─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part
```

The above information shows that Ubuntu is installed because the HDD is now mounted.
As a fresh Ubuntu user I don't know what to try next.

Please note that Windows 10 is working fine, may be there is something which I should try from it (I tried many things here, but got no luck) and I want dual boot with Ubuntu installed on 500 GB detachable HDD along with presence of Windows 10 on 30 GB SSD, not vice versa. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is UEFI fast boot on? And is Windows fast start up on? And is UEFI Secure boot on.  But some systems still boot so quick that USB powered external drive is not up to speed in time to be seen for boot. And some systems only boot from internal drives. It looks like you may have Ubuntu installed in BIOS boot mode, which requires you to interupt boot and choose to boot from that drive with UEFI boot key, often f10 or f12. Does your table even have that type of setting?  see this for UEFI/gpt partitioning. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: It looks like your problem has to do with GRUB configuration and install location. Which disk has GRUB installed? Specifically, which disk is your BIOS booting from when it loads GRUB?

Comment: Thanks rplaughlin and @oldfred currently grub is installed on 30GB SSD and on the boot it loads it form the same disk. 
In the beginning, I installed Ubuntu on 500 GB detachable HDD and in the device boot loader location I mentioned that one, but ended with same problem. so I reinstalled it and changed boot loader location to 30 GB SSD.

Comment: There is one thing I have forgotten to mention that when I get the Haier Y11b tablet PC then I installed Ubuntu on 128 GB SSD external HDD connected through USB cable and I used it for many weeks without facing any problem. But it was weird and frustrating to attach each time external HDD with cable for using Ubuntu that's why I decided to installed it on 500 GB detachable HDD. 
I don't know why, but It detects all drives connected through USB but it can't detect even load it own detachable external HDD at the start up.

Comment: Thanks @oldfred   I checked windows fast start up and it was on  and I made it off and tried to boot Ubuntu too, but didn't work. 
 My secure boot is off. 
 I checked the BIOS mode and its "UEFI" and from the link you suggested I confirmed that my both windows and Ubuntu installed in "UEFI" mode.
 I checked but I didn't find any option for UEFI fast boot I think I don't have any option for enabling/disabling it.

Comment: @oldfred My BIOS info is "version 2.17/1249 copyright (c) 2016 American Megatrends, Inc." and it contains options the following options 
1. UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell 
2. Launch EFI Shell from filesystem device 
may be I can try something form here.

I think you'r right the problem is that as you mentioned "some systems still boot so quick that USB powered external drive is not up to speed in time to be seen for boot" because HDD data access indicator lamp doesn't blink.

Comment: Can you power external drive separately & turn it on before you boot?

Comment: I can't do that because [Haier Y11b tablet PC ] 
(http://www.haier.com/pk/products/pc/Tablet_PC/y11b.shtml) contain a standalone detachable part consists of 500 GB HDD, mouse pad and a keyboard.

Comment: If you have a powered USB hub, then you can probably use that to power the drive separately and start up the disk before you start to boot your tablet PC.